# HP PSC 2175 scanner installation

Tags: drivers, scanner

I have an HP PSC 2175 all in one printer, scanner and copier. When I tried to install it on my computer with my new Ubuntu OS all that installed was the printer. All I did was plug in the cable from the printer/scanner and the pinter was intalled but not the scanner. Do you have any idea why this is or any suggestions how to fix it.

Comment: How did you install it ?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to enter Synaptic and install HPLIP and XSANE. With those packages installed you'll have full performance of your printing/scanning device.